# Enforcing security restrictions on table rows via default schema and views on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security

We have an application which database relies on SQL Server 2000. A specific area of this application let users access rows from a table that they shouldn't: they should only access rows from suppliers, but not rows from customers. Both suppliers and customers are stored on a single table. We can't change this particular area of the application to limit access, and the vendor wouldn't change it on the near future.

So, as a DBA, I am thinking about creating a solution (until the vendor creates the definitive solution) on the database:

- The name of the table containing the data is called **dbo.FOOBAR**.
- I would create a new login and a new user on the database called **newuser**.
- After, I would create a view called **newuser.FOOBAR**, with a SELECT statement selecting only the rows the user should have access from **dbo.FOOBAR**.
- On the application, I can associate the user application with a user accessing the database.

With this possible solution, the user would login to the database as **newuser**. Any statement involving the table **FOOBAR** would involve **newuser.FOOBAR** automatically because of the default schema.

I made some tests and it seems to work. The table **dbo.FOOBAR** has an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE trigger, and it seems to work after updates, inserts and deletes using the view.

I question is: is this a preferred way of enforcing a security access without changing the application? Is there some caveat I should consider? Is there another solution for this problem?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the application keeps working correctly this method appears to be a workable solution.  It probably isn't the preferred solution as you'll need to be careful when doing any upgrades that they are run by a DBO, and if new columns are added to the dbo.FOOBAR table (It's actually FUBAR) that you rebuild the newuser.FOOBAR view so that it picks up the new columns.